# Habilitar boton dentro de panel deshabilitado en VB o C#

Tags: vb.net

En un panel padre tengo varios controles, uno de ellos es un boton, el detalle es que el panel padre esta deshabilitado y por lo tanto el boton tambien aparece deshabilitado, ¿se puede habilitar unicamente el boton? y ¿como lo podria hacer? ya que intente habilitarlo recorriendo los controles del panel, pero no funciona ya que no habilita el boton, lo realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
                    For Each ObjControl In Me.Panel5.Controls                        
                        Dim nombreControl As String = ObjControl.NAME
                        If nombreControl = "Button3" Then
                            Me.Button3.Enabled = True
                        End If
                    Next
```

Comment: Una pregunta. El problema es que la línea no se ejecuta, o que la sentencia no funciona?

Comment: @Arriel el problema es que no me habilita el Button3 dentro del panel5

Comment: no podes.. si el padre esta deshabilitado, todos sus hijos tambien...

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer-lo así:

```
                For Each ObjControl In Me.Panel5.Controls                        
                    If ObjControl.Name = "Button3" Then
                        ObjControl.Enabled = True
                    End If
                Next
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, agrega una explicación de que realiza tu código, revisa [answer], saludos.